# How to pass string array to php slim api using angular frontend

Tags: php, angular, rest, slim

I'm using angular and php slim to create a web based system. Now I want to send string array to php slim api. And access it from backend. I use following code for now. But it is not working correctly.

Angular Front End Code.

```
    var emails  = ['sampleemail@gmail.com','anotheremail96@gmail.com'];
    this._db.sendFirstEmailToAllEmp(emails).subscribe((result : any) => {
      console.log(result);
    },(error : any) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Slim PHP Api Backend Code

```
// Send First Mail When Customer Send A Job
$app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    try{
        // Get The Array 
        $result = array();
        $emails = $request->getParsedBody();
        $length = $request->getContentLength();
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
            $tempEmail = $emails[$i];
            $result[$i] = $tempEmail;
        }
        // Return Result
        return $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')->write(json_encode($result));
    } catch(Exception $ex){
        $result = array();
        $result["TYPE"] = "ERROR";
        $result["CODE"] = $ex->getCode();
        $result["MSG"] = $ex->getMessage();
        $result["FILE"] = $ex->getFile();
        $result["LINE"] = $ex->getLine();
        return $response->withStatus(400)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')->write(json_encode($result));
    }
});
```

I want to get those emails in back end for i can do other things related to the array.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpClient to make a POST request

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


sendEmailFunction(email) { 
   this.http.post('yourUrl', {email}).subscribe(); 
}
```

And in your backend you can access to the email with

```
$request->email;
```

Don't forget to change the type of the route to post

```
$app->post(...)
```